# Cannot import PSSession for "management"?

Tags: powershell

I already create a remote session and I can run script block on the session

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName S1
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem c:\ } -Session $session
```

Now I want to do the following for easier typing.

```
Get-S1ChildItem c:\
```

So I did the following

```
Import-PSSession -Session $session -Module management -Prefix S1
```

However, it got the following error.

```
Import-PSSession : Running the Get-Command command in a remote session returned no results.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-PSSession -Session $session -Module management -Prefix S1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Import-PSSession], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ErrorNoResultsFromRemoteEnd,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportPSSessionCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works fine when replacing `-Module management` with `-Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'`. The `Invoke-Command` is not really needed, to be able to use remote CmdLets.

Please try the following:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName S1
Import-PSSession -Session $session -Prefix S1 -Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Management'
Get-S1ChildItem c:\
```

This proves that all CmdLets from the remote session in the module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management` are available, as described in the [help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849970(v=wps.630).aspx) of `Import-PSSession`.

To find out in which module a CmdLet can be found, you can use:

```
Get-Command Get-ChildItem | Select-Object ModuleName
```